# Python/Matplotlib - Colorbar indicating a mean value

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

Is it possible to indicate a mean value on the colorbar?

I have the following plots, showing the surface "temperature" (Radiance) of a sahara section, and now it would be nice to see the mean value on the colorbar indicated by an arrow or something.

The difference between the plots is the band/channel/wavelength the measurement was taken in and there is a slight difference. Especially, when I'm going to compare the data from season to season.

[image: Plot showing radiance distribution of a Sahara section]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a colorbar to the plot using `plt.colorbar()`, matplotlib creates a new axis for the colorbar returns the colorbar object.  The axis the colorbar is plotted on is scaled from 0 to 1 in both x and y and is referenced as the `.ax` property of the colorbar object.  We can use value min and max from the colorbar to map where on the axis the mean should be drawn.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = np.random.normal(1, 4, 450).reshape(-1, 15)
plt.imshow(data)
# capture the colorbar object, rescale mean to the axis
cb = plt.colorbar()
mean_loc = (data.mean() - cb.vmin) / (cb.vmax - cb.vmin)

# add a horizontal line to the colorbar axis
cb.ax.hlines(mean_loc, 0, 1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: exactly what I needed! Thank you very much :) Didn't know that matplotlib creates a new axis for the colorbar that we can work with like that. I guess I can add a lable around the same location saying "mean". Gonna try it out now